# Cakephp pagination custom order

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, paginator

I need to set the pagination order of my register based on field (`$results[$key]['Movimento']['status']`) created in afterFind callback.

afterFind:

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {

    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        if(isset($val['Movimento']['data_vencimento'])) {
            $data = $val['Movimento']['data_vencimento'];
            $dtVc = strtotime($data);
            $dtHj = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
            $dtVencendo = strtotime("+7 day", $dtHj);
            if ($dtVc < $dtHj) {
                $results[$key]['Movimento']['status'] = 'vencido';
            } elseif ($dtVc <= $dtVencendo) {
                $results[$key]['Movimento']['status'] = 'vc15dias';
            } else {
                $results[$key]['Movimento']['status'] = 'aberto';
            }
        }
        if(isset($val['Movimento']['data_pagamento'])) {
            $results[$key]['Movimento']['status'] = 'quitado';
        }
    }
    return $results;
```

Pagination:

```
$options = array(
            ...
            'order' => array('Movimento.status' => 'ASC')
        );
$this->controller->paginate = $options;
$movimentos = $this->controller->paginate('Movimento');
```

I know this does not work because the field is created after the paginator call.

Can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understand, you want to sort by `data_pagamento` and than by `data_vencimento` (has it the mysql-type `date`?)

so you don't need your afterFind-function for ordering, simply use:

```
'order' => array(
    'Movimento.data_pagamento DESC',//first all rows with not-empty data_pagamento
    'Movimento.data_vencimento DESC',// first all dates in the furthest future
)
```

Comment: It works around 95% for what I need because the "data_pagamento" must be ASC to work, but ok. The correct code: 'order' => array('Movimento.data_pagamento' => 'ASC', 'Movimento.data_vencimento' => 'ASC')